# DatePicker not closing in iOS when click another field

Tags: ios, mgwt

I have a mobile app that consistently does not close the DatePicker if I go to another data entry field on iOS.  I have to click "Done".  In other words, I click on "date" field ( MDateBox ), then click on "number" field ( MDoubleBox ).  "Number" field still has the date picker displayed in this case.  I see this even happens with JQueryUI on iOS, but I don't know how to get around it in the MGWT context.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Tony

Comment: Did you solved this problem ?

Comment: No, not yet.  I did confirm that it seems to be related to iPhone more than iPad.  The behavior is different between the two devices, at least, as well as the look and feel, which I guess makes sense.  I suppose it could have something to do with Cordova, but I just don't see how as I don't see any Date related code inside Cordova xCode project.

Comment: Is this a iOS problem, and cordova problem, or what?  I see lots of cordova datepicker plugins, but that does not make sense as a perfectly good DatePicker comes up, except for this one problem.